# BOOST_FOREACH crash on boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost

Trying todo a simple on a vector of shared_ptr and it crashes? I am suspecting I am doing something obviously wrong?

```
std::vector< shared_ptr<SUBCLASS> > m_vecSections;

shared_ptr<SUBCLASS> hoodSection;
BOOST_FOREACH(hoodSection, m_vecSections ){
   //do something
}
```

I am getting a crash in

```
 void add_ref_copy()
{
    atomic_increment( &use_count_ );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a small test case that repros the problem and that we can look at/compile?

Comment: Rule of 3 on SUBCLASS, maybe? Your FOREACH will invoke copy constructor...

Comment: There is nothing in the identified code that could potentially cause a crash. Please post a minimal code sample that still exhibit the issue... if you really wish answers. Note that you could be using `BOOST_FOREACH(std::shared_ptr<SUBCLASS> const& hoodSection, m_vecSections)` to avoid the copy issue, but it's not strictly equivalent.

Comment: thankyou for your answers it was a mem-release issue caused by somewhere else. Just kept crashing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou guys

You had no chance to find it, a call like this...

weak_ptr weakHood(shared_ptr(this));

released the m_vecSections and caused the crash...

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax should be:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(shared_ptr<SUBCLASS> hoodSection , m_vecSections ){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding or removing elements from `m_vecSections` inside the `BOOST_FOREACH`?

That can lead to undefined behavior because `BOOST_FOREACH` caches the end iterator (so it'll become invalid if the vector is changed). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html

Comment: Well the memory was being collected by the boost::shared_ptr that lead to the weird behaviour